# How to restrict jquery-calendar past-date selection base on database table information in-mvc5

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

Work on asp.net mvc5.Need to restrict past date on my calendar.I know how to restrict past date's in jquery calendar .

**Model**

```
public class EmpModel    
{   
   [Display(Name ="Enter Date")]    
   public DateTime EnterDate { get; set; }    
}
```

**View J-query is**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#EnterDate").datepicker({  
        dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",  
        minDate: -0,  
        maxDate: "+0M +0D"  

    });  
});
```

**Problem** is Have one database table named **DateConfigure** base on this table information need to set the jquery **minDate** and **maxDate** property values for restriction of date selection.

**DateConfigure table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateConfigure](
    [DateConfigId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MinDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MaxDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DateConfigure] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DateConfigId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Table data**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DateConfigure] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[DateConfigure] ([DateConfigId], [MinDate], [MaxDate], [IsActive]) VALUES (2, N'-0', N'+0M +0D', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DateConfigure] ([DateConfigId], [MinDate], [MaxDate], [IsActive]) VALUES (3, N'-0', N'+0M +5D', 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DateConfigure] ([DateConfigId], [MinDate], [MaxDate], [IsActive]) VALUES (4, N'-0', N'+0M +4D', 0)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DateConfigure] OFF
GO
```

What to do how to set date restriction base on database table information.

Comment: Pass the min and max dates to you view so that you can use ` minDate: @Model.MinDate` (or `@ViewBag.MinDate` etc